Camunda WebApp doesn't work with spring.mvc.servlet.path
I have a spring boot application and I try to implement a camunda application.
My properties look like:
spring.mvc.servlet.path=/my-app/v1

When I run my application, it runs successfully. And I can reach the app from /my-app/v1 but I couldn't camunda dashboard with these paths
/my-app/v1/camunda/
/my-app/v1/camunda/app/
/my-app/v1/camunda/app/cockpit
/camunda/
/camunda/app/
/camunda/app/cockpit

Is there a way to handle it in Spring Boot?

Can you share which version of Camunda you are using?

Here is the code @Samantha https://github.com/senolatac/camunda-demo

<camunda.version>7.21.0</camunda.version>

By default camunda uses this property
for application path. You can tweak it based on your need.  https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/configuration/#camunda-engine-properties
camunda.bpm.webapp.application-path=/camunda  Note : It will not move the /engine-rest endpoints. You have to use spring.jersey.application-path=/engine-rest  for REST APIS
